# Google Sheets Macro Color Cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

Is there a way to write a continuously running script in google sheets where it scans the sheet to find any cell with a certain text and the color that and the adjacent cell a certain color?

So here's my sheet

```
------------------------------------
| ColA            | ColB           |
------------------------------------
| CellA1          | CellB1         |
------------------------------------
| CellA2          | CellB2         |
------------------------------------
| CellA3          | CellB3         |
------------------------------------
```

I want to find the row with `ColA = 'CellA1'` and then color both that cell and the adjacent cell, `CellB1`, a particular color.

And I want to make it continous so that when I insert a new row and type in `CellA1` for `ColA` then it'll automatically color it a certain color after I hit enter.

Answer (score 2):

Use the built in **Conditional Formatting** found in the *Formatting* menu.  You will apply it to range `A2:B` and set *format cells if...* to `Custom formula Is` which is at the bottom of the list.  The formula you enter is `=$A2="CellA1"`  Then select the color and other formatting you may like.
[image]

Comment: oh cool, yeah this works! But it only colors the cells under `ColA`. How do I tell it to color both cells in `ColA` and `ColB`

Comment: Did you set the range to A2:B  ?  That should get both.  Or at least it did in my test.  Note, by Range, I mean the _Apply to Range_ item.

Comment: I added an image of my settings.